# How do I get WebComponent classes to invoke my custom constructor?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I created a WebComponent where I created a constructor for it.  When run, this constructor does not seem to be invoked, though the rest of the components work, but they have to be created outside my custom constructor.  Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```html
<element name="x-navigation" constructor="Navigation" extends="div">
    <template>
        <div>{{items}}</div>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart">
        import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

        class Navigation extends WebComponent {
          List<String> items = new List<String>();
          Navigation() {
              items.add("Hello");
          }
        }
    </script>
<element>
```

If I include this component, the output will be an empty list, as if the constructor I created has not been called.  There should be at least the "Hello" string output, but it isn't. Are constructors created this way ignored, or have I missed something?

Comment: This happened to me, too, so I opened a bug to request more feedback from the compiler when it notices we accidentally do this: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/272

Comment: @SeathLadd That's a good idea, as it threw me for quiet a while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version of Web UI now calls the constructor, and there is also the `created` lifecycle method available for you.

The following code is adding both hello's:

```html
<element name="x-navigation" constructor="Navigation" extends="div">
  <template>
    <div>{{items}}</div>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

    class Navigation extends WebComponent {
      List<String> items = new List<String>();

      Navigation() {
        items.add("Hello first");
      }

      created() {
        items.add("Hello second");
      }
    }
  </script>
<element>
```

I recommend reading the article on lifecycle methods: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/spec.html#lifecycle-methods

### Lifecycle methods

**created()** - Invoked slightly after a component is created.

**inserted()** - Invoked whenever a component is added to the DOM.

**attributeChanged()** - Invoked whenever an attribute in the component changes.

**removed()** - Invoked whenever a component is removed from the DOM

Comment: Thanks, but why is the constructor I created not used?

Comment: @JamesHurford I believe it's because they need to do some processing before they let you run your initialization code. If you look at the `out` directory and the compiled source code, it seems this is the case.

Comment: Kai Sellgren is this still the case with the constructor? I was able to create a constructor from a class that extended WebComponent.

Answer (score 1):

Add following method in class:

```
created() {
   items.add("Hello");
 }
```